# git clone by https does not work on other machine

Tags: git, gitlab

On my local machine(Linux), I clone the repo with

```
git clone https://rcffc@dev.kom.e-technik.tu-darmstadt.de/gitlab/WaelKH/KM_2_2017_Feature_Selection.git
```

and it asks me for my password. After typing the password I can clone the repository, fine.

On the server(Windows), the command leads to

```
remote: Not Found
fatal: repository 'git clone https://rcffc@dev.kom.e-technik.tu-darmstadt.de/gitlab/WaelKH/KM_2_2017_Feature_Selection.git/' not found
```

Please help me.

UPDATE: It is a private repository.
UPDATE 2&3: Made question clearer.
UPDATE 4: Included OS info
UPDATE 5: Included actual commands.

Comment: Who tells you to clone with `git clone https://username@remote.git`?

Comment: Gitlab tells me to do so.

Comment: Show me the link please.

Comment: That's only a placeholder example

Comment: Exactly: remote should be the "remote" link. Something like www.example.com/foo/bar.git, ... not only bar.git.

Comment: @sensorario Yes I have done it like this. I can also access the page in a browser..

Comment: Is a private repository? Mmmm maybe you must copy the remote's ssh public key on gitlab. I suppose you copied your local public ssh key. Gitlab MUST know all ssh keys of computer that can clone/push/... from/to it.

Comment: Oh dear, your cloning the user name. Just use the https web link of the repo or ssh link of the repo you want to clone.

Answer (score 1):

Try to check if `curl https://username@remote.git` works. First, as @sensorario mentioned, you should make sure your URL is valid, and you should also guarantee that `curl` is using the right certificate for the https connections since AFAIK git commands internally uses curl.

UPDATE

`git clone https://your_server_ip/your_user_name/your_repo_name.git`

Comment: It returns <html><body>You are being <a href="https://xxxxxxx/sign_in">redirected</a>.</body></html>

Comment: you should provide ssh key to pass the sign in part to gain repo access

Comment: The machine is a server where I share the User with others, so ssh probably is not a good idea

Comment: @PeterJiang I'm trying to figure out an answer for you. Is it a private repo hosted on gitlab.com or your own remote server?

Comment: It is a development server running Gitlab

Comment: I was wrong. Try this : `git clone git@your_server_ip:your_user_name/your_repo_name.git`

Comment: That could work, but I don't want to use SSH since other people are using the same account on the server. Note that the https works perfectly on my machine.

Comment: HTTPS version is this : `git clone https://your_server_ip/your_user_name/your_repo_name.git`

Comment: Ok thanks I will report back later when I can access the server.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146193/discussion-between-peter-jiang-and-viz).

Answer (score 0):

The command to clone a repository stored in http://www.example.com/foo/bar.git is

```
git clone https://www.example.com/foo/bar.git
```